# Подключение к базе данных H2 из Spring Boot

Tags: java, база-данных, spring-boot, spring-jpa, h2

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД H2. Использую Spring Boot.

pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties

```ini
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/villagebank
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

# H2 settings
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Открываю `http://localhost:8090/h2` попадаю на страницу логина, жму `Test connection` и получаю ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему? Попытался зайти в Preferences но там нужен admin password которого у меня нет, поискал его в гугле информации не нашел.
Соответственно дальше все что я делаю в приложении тоже вызывает ошибки.

Скрин подключения Н2 в IDEA

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Настройка БД H2 в Spring Boot приложении

Корректный URL для подключения к БД, которая находится

- на диске в домашней папке: [jdbc:h2:~/dbname](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html);
- на диске в текущем каталоге: [jdbc:h2:./path/to/database](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases);
- в памяти: [jdbc:h2:mem:dbname](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource)

В Spring Boot для встроенных (embedded) БД используется `testdb` в качесве имени БД по умолчанию (см. пункт [DATA PROPERTIES/DATASOURCE/spring.datasource.name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties))

Таким образом, для работы с H2 в Spring Boot, по умолчанию, нужно использовать такие параметры подключения:

```ini
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

В `application.properties` их не нужно указывать - Spring Boot сам поднимет БД с параметрами по умолчанию (если H2 присутствует в проекте). Явно эти свойства имеет смысл указываеть только если вы хотите изменить имя БД или разместить ее на диске.

---

Для работы с БД H2 при разработке Spring Boot приложения, я рекомендую использовать не встроенную консоль H2, а следующий подход, который позволяет подключить БД непосредственно в IDE (или в другом, более удобном инструменте для работы с БД, чем консоль H2):

1. В настройках зависимости H2 убираем scope "runtime":

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
   </dependency>
   ```
2. В классе с `@Configuration` (или в классе `Application`) объявляем бин H2 сервера (который будем включать Spring Boot профилем "dev"):

   ```java
   @Profile("dev")
   @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
   public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
      return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp","-tcpAllowOthers","-tcpPort","9092");
   }
   ```
3. Запускаем приложение и, **после этого**, подключаем БД в IDE

   ```
   url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:testdb
   user: sa
   password:
   ```

---

Связанные материалы:

- [How to access in memory h2 database of one spring boot application from another spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276769/5380322)
- [Default url and credentials for H2DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45925944/5380322)