# Проблема с подключением к H2

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, hsqldb

Смотрю учебный проект по работе с БД.
Основная база там MySQL, а в тестах используется H2, вот помник:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

В файле `application.properties` прописаны следующие настройки:

```yaml
jdbc:
  driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  pool.size.max: 10
  statement.timeout: 0
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:mytestdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
  username: sa
  password:
```

Тест проходит, т.е. в базу заносятся данные, проверяются, все ОК.

Вот только когда я запускаю тест в режиме дебага, ставлю точку останова в конце теста и пытаюсь подключиться к БД, то там пусто, нет даже таблиц, не то что данных.
Для подключения использую DBever.
В строке подключения прописываю `jdbc:h2:mem:mytestdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`
(пробовал и так `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:mytestdb`).
Проверка соединения проход, пишет, что все ок, соединение установлено.
В чем может быть проблема?
Вопрос по этой теме [подключение к БД H2...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969101/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-h2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-spring-boot) смотрел, все равно не получается

Answer (score 2):

БД H2, он же ранее Hypersonic работает или в режиме `in-memory` или `file`, судя по url вашего JDBC `jdbc:h2:mem:mytestdb` - у вас режим `in-memory`, вам надо выбрать `jdbc:h2:file:mytestdb` - тогда будет обеспечена запись в файл и тогда вы сможете увидеть записи и проч.

Comment: пробовал я с файлом, вместо url: jdbc:h2:mem:ump-currencymanager;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
прописал:
url: jdbc:h2:file:c:\logs\logdb
Файл создается, когда я открываю его с помощью DBever, и даже таблицы там есть, но в самих таблицах нет данных. Может в этом случае что-то с доступом не так. Я пробовал подключатьься и во время выполнения теста и после, все равно пусто.